# KivyMD > MDRaisedButton > Adjust font size to fit inside MDRaisedButton

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I am using MDRaisedButtons in my app and they look perfect on my windows laptop and on my high resolution android phone.  However, on smaller, lower resolution phones the button text is very big and does not fit inside the button.

I am using KivyMD 0.104.1 which I believe is the latest release version and Kivy 2.0.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using `font_size: Window.width / 100` (if portrait app) or `Window.height / 100` (if landscape), (100 is just a random value, adjust however u want)

Comment: @YashKolekar thanks, that seems to be the answer but unfortunately, I have an instance on one mobile where the resolution is the same as my high resolution phone but the text in the MDRaisedButtons are scaling up and are much bigger.